# New Facebook app creation: "Oops - Something went wrong" error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to create this Facebook app to access Graph API - following the usual procedure at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/create/, I start filling in the form (App name, contact email and the optional business account -- which I'm not using atm)

Then I am requested to reenter my password "for my security", and after that I get a "Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can." message, and apparently, regardless how much I try, cannot move past that.

Tried so far: disabled adblock, cleared cache and cookies, switched from Chrome to Safari, tried from a different computer and account: nothing seems to get past this "Something went wrong" error.